# VBA Object variable or with block

Tags: vba, excel, object

I keep getting the

> Object variable or with block variable not

set error even though I have defined all variables. I know there are plenty of other questions regarding this being asked here, however non of them seem to help me.

I am simply trying to update a number of graphs. I have used the code before in other workbooks, which is why i cannot find the error.

```
Sub Update_All_Graphs()
    Call SETWorksheets

    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim ShName As String
    Dim FindRow, FindRowNumber As Double

    Set FindRow = ScTotalWs.Range("AF10:AF47").Find(What:="Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues)
    FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
    Lastrow = FindRowNumber - 1

    ScTotalWs.ChartObjects("1_EOST").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("AJ10:AJ" & Lastrow & ", AK10:AK" & Lastrow & ", AL10:AL" & Lastrow)
End Sub
```

The error shows up on the `FindrowNumber = FindRow.row` line.

Comment: define `FindRowNumber` As `Long`, so `FindRowNumber As Double` sould be also `FindRowNumber As Long`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Object+variable+or+with+block+variable+not+set%22

Comment: you also need to trap the case the `Find` was unsuccesful, with `If Not FindRow is Nothing Then`

Comment: FindRow should be declared as a Range also.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Range.Find()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) is not guaranteed to return anything (logical, if you think about it). The documentation states clearly:

> #### Remarks
>
> This method returns `Nothing` if no match is found.

Never use the result of such a method call without checking that it is valid.

```
Set FindRow = ScTotalWs.Range("AF10:AF47").Find(What:="Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then
    Lastrow = FindRow.Row - 1
    ' etc
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

`Find()` method of `Range` object has a subtle trap in that it assumes for some parameters, if not explicitly declared, their *last* value, with *last* being   their values used during the last use of that method, even if from Excel UI!

so you'd better always explicitly specify all those parameters and assure you're actually searching as you want it to be done:

```
Set FindRow = ScTotalWs.Range("AF10:AF47").Find(What:="Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

but you could also avoid the setting and checking against `Nothing` of the `Range` object returned by the `Range` object `Find()` method by using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf()` function, as follows:

```
Sub Update_All_Graphs()
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    With ScTotalWs.Range("AF10:AF47") '<--| reference relevant range of wanted worksheet
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "Grand Total") > 0 Then '<--| if there's at least one occurrence of "Grand Total"
            Lastrow = .Find(What:="Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).row - 1 '<--| set your 'LastRow'
            With .Parent '<--| reference the parent worksheet of referenced range, for all subsequent ranges references
                .ChartObjects("1_EOST").Activate
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
                ActiveChart.SetSourceData source:=.Range("AJ10:AJ" & Lastrow & ", AK10:AK" & Lastrow & ", AL10:AL" & Lastrow)
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This would still fail if `.Find()` would return `Nothing`.

Comment: @Tomalak, it can't since there's the previous check with CountIf() to make it sure there's at least one occurrence of the wanted value

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Should have been made explicit, as Find() usally calls for result verification.

Comment: @Tomalak, I wrote it quite clearly right before typing in the code

Comment: Oh well. Of course you did. The upvote was mine, so there is not much else I csn do.

Comment: @Tomalak, thank you for upvote. I didn't mean to ask you for anything. I just commented after you because my understanding was you didn't notice my explicit explanation about CountIf() making the check of Find() result against Nothing unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to define "ScTotalWs".

```
Set ScTotalWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")
```

Of course,  you need to Change [Table1] according to your file.

Comment: Why, when the error occurs one line later? If that was the problem, the error would occur on the line where `ScTotalWs` is used, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, as I have defined all worksheets in a different module.

Comment: @Tomalak you are right, my bad, did not read the last sentence :-(